# How to add a root certificate to the truststore used by openssl?

Tags: openssl, trusted-root-certificates

Not sure why, but the system truststore of Ubuntu and the truststore used by openssl are not the same (not mentioning Java truststores here).

I managed to add our root certificate to the system truststore as well as the Java truststore, but I can't find how to add it to the **openssl truststore**?

I'm referring to Ubuntu 22.04.1 if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra
sudo cp root.cert.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra/root.cert.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```